# Entity Framework duplicate primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and sqlite to store and retrieve some data. When the following code block runs, an exception is thrown on `db.SaveChanges()`.

```
using (var db = new RepoDatabase(DBPath))
{
    var folder1 = new Folder
    {
        Name = "name1",
        Subtitle = "subtitle",
        ParentFolder = null,
        IsHidden = false,
        IsSimple = true,
        QueryOrFilePath = "query"
    };

    var folder2 = new Folder
    {
        Name = "name2",
        Subtitle = "subtitle",
        ParentFolder = folder1,
        IsHidden = false,
        IsSimple = true,
        QueryOrFilePath = "query"
    };
    db.Folders.Add(folder1);
    db.Folders.Add(folder2);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Exception:

> 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in   EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'RhythmRepository.Folder_ParentFolder' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

From my understanding, this problem often occurs when the ID is used directly for foreign keys, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, as the type of "ParentFolder" is "Folder".

The folder type is set to auto-increment in the database, and has the attribute:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

The underlying entity structure:

```
class Folder
{
    #region database fields
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FolderID")]
    public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    public bool IsSimple { get; set; }
    public string QueryOrFilePath { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

And the SQL query to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Folders 
(
    FolderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Subtitle varchar(255) NULL,
    ParentFolderID INT NULL,
    IsHidden BIT NOT NULL,
    IsSimple BIT NOT NULL,
    QueryOrFilePath varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ParentFolderID) REFERENCES Folders(FolderID)
);
```

Comment: what is the mapping for the self-join Folder-Parentfolder? In one-to-one, the PK is used as FK, and this cannot work in this case because of obvious reasons.

Comment: It's a one to many relationship. Folders have references to their parents, and many folders can share the same parent.

Comment: It's worth sharing the entity structure and how you defined relationship mappings.

Comment: added. I wasn't sure if they were needed originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the part

```
[ForeignKey("FolderID")]
public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
```

This makes EF think that `FolderID` is the foreign key to the parent `Folder`. In reality, it's `ParentFolderID`. So change your class definition and mapping to

```
class Folder
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FolderID { get; set; }

    public int? ParentFolderID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentFolderID")]
    public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

If `FolderID` is the foreign key, EF concludes that there is a 1:1 association between a folder and its parent. Normally, a 1:1 association is implemented by a primary key that's also the foreign key to the parent. I.e the child's primary key copies its parent's primary key. When parent and child are the same entity class, two records of the same table would have to have the same primary key --impossible.

Comment: I thought that the foreign key attribute was for telling EF which column of the corresponding table was the primary key. The change you suggested makes sense, but even after implementing it, I still get the same exception in the same place.

Comment: This is almost the entire solution. the missing piece is that ParentFolderID must be of type int? instead of int. Once both sets of changes have been made everything works perfectly